# SmartCard: APDU command READ_BINARY returns error: Wrong parameters P1-P2

Tags: java, smartcard, apdu

I am trying to read a file that is under MF.  The EF.DIR file. I got the file's **SFID**, so I don't use the method SELEC_FILE first (since it's not necessary). 
I might be having some problems with understanding the **P2** parameter (the OFFSET). I read couple of explanations, but still don't get what *OFFSET* do they mean. But I tried all the numbers from 0-8 just in case, none worked.

```
CLA = 0x00
INS_READ = 0xB0
P1_READ = 0x9E (by the datasheed: bit(8) = 1, bit(7:6) = 00, bit(5:1): SFID)
P2 = 0x04 (I figured that the offset should be from bit0 to bit4 (the SFID)
Le = 0 (by the datasheet I have, this should mean that any size will be returned)
```

**This is my code:**

```
byte[] readBinary = { CLA, INS_READ, P1_READ, (byte) 0x04, (short) 0};
ResponseAPDU  read = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(readBinary));
String responseReadToString =read.toString();
System.out.println("Response Read: " + responseReadToString + "\n" + "Response Read (HEX): " + responseReadHex );
```

**The output I get in Console is:**

```
Response Read: ResponseAPDU: 2 bytes, SW=6b00
Response Read (HEX): 6B00
```

Explanations of SW1-SW2 for 6B00:

```
Incorrect parameters P1-P2
```

I really don't know what is wrong and it's really hard to find support on SmartCards online, so hopefully someone who knows this better can help me out. I also tried with using SELECT_FILE first and the use READ_BINARY after it (without the SFID in P1 parametr ofcourse), but it responded with "No EF is set as current".

Any help guys?

Comment: There ARE some (a little bit:) dated and not perfectly legal copies of ISO 7816-4 on the internet. You will have a very hard time not having digested that one.

Comment: What card are you working with and what are its specs?

Answer (score 1):

The offset is the position/startpoint from where you start reading.

Example: Data = [0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05]

When you query a ReadBinary with offset=2 then returned data will be [0x02 0x03 0x4 0x05]

As you probably want to read the whole EF.DIR file offset shall be zero.

For reading EF.DIR you can either send

```
00 B0 9E 00 00
```

or

```
00 B1 2F 00 04 54 02 00 00 00
```

or

```
00 A4 02 0C 02 2F 00
00 B0 00 00 00
```

Comment: Thank you Paul, I will test one of your solutions. I would like to find an example how the SELEC_FILE and READ_BINARY actually works in the code? I mean if you check my code, you see I use `chanell.transmit(new CommandAPDU(readBinary);`. In option with SELECT_FILE, I assume I'd have to use first the command for SELECT_FILE and right after the READ_BINARY command. However,  if I do that, it says that I haven't selected any file. Which is weird, since I did right before the READ_BINARY.

Comment: I have tried all of the above mentioned methods, but none have worked for my case. Can you please provide me with an Example code on how does SELECT_FILE and READ_BINARY afterwards work? Because the error says: No Current EF.

Comment: You should try sending these APDUs in a good-working smartcard shell/pcsc suite, e.g. openSC etc

Comment: I insert the card and ASAP send a bunch of commands. They fails with SW 6986 / 6B00. I redo the sequence, waiting two seconds after card insertion : all fine.

Comment: are you using Windows? there is a service that imports certificates and immediately sends commands when a new smartcard is detected, this service might disturb your commands. you can disable that, though I don't know the exact name in English(German:zertifikatsverteilung) something like: certificate distribution